# Navigating with arrow keys

Tags: keyboard, navigation, usability, spatial

What are some generally accepted practices for navigating between irregularly placed and sized elements in a canvas (such as controls on a form) using the arrow keys?

For example, if the currently focused element is a tall element (A) whose height encompasses three shorter elements to the right of it (B, C and D):

```
#######    #######
#     #    #  B  #
#     #    #######
#     #
#     #    #######
#  A  #    #  C  #
#     #    #######
#     #  
#     #    #######
#     #    #  D  #
#######    #######
```

Which of these elements should be focused when the user presses the `Right` arrow?  The top element (B)?  The one in the center (C)?

What if D was focused before the use user moved focus to A by pressing `Left`?  Should focus return to D when the user subsequently presses `Right`?

I'm wondering if there are some published guidelines for these scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked into any specific guidelines or anything, but it seems that in the first case, when you're on A and you push Right, it should go to B.

If you're already on C or D when you push A, it probably makes sense to go back to that one. I'm less sure about this one, because the user might have gone to A from the bottom as a "shortcut" to get to B (This makes sense if there are a lot of elements in the right column, so instead of going (Up-Up-Up-Up-Up-Up you go Left-Right).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's also important to note what element 'B' is that you're navigating to.  Suppose B is a text box.  If you go from A to B, will you assume the user wants to enter input and automatically focus their cursor in the text box?  This would give a user immediate use of typing into the box, but immediate problems if he/she wanted to move to C or D instead.

I think it's more important to give the user feedback on which field he/she is in.  Windows controls tend to suck for showing a well highlighted field, while in OS X, you get a distinctive highlight around the control that is selected (in most cases).

Just make it a point not to get in the way of the user if they want to go somewhere else.  Don't lock down their keyboard after moving into A-D if they only want to move to another element.

Answer (score 1):

In general, navigating through controls should follow the user's natural reading order.  In Western cultures, that's left-to-right, top-to-bottom.  This has been a usability standard at Microsoft going back to the excellent [The Windows Interface Guidelines for Software Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556156790) and [Microsoft Windows User Experience](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735605661).

In your example, navigation through the controls should go A-B-C-D-A-...

Answer (score 0):

If you're on A and you hit right, you should go to B.

If you're on D, and you hit Left, there are two options: "going left", which is A, or "going back", which would mean going to B. If you choose the second way, there's no place to get lost, although it can look a bit weird at first.

That said, if you choose the first way, I think the proper would be going to B: no need to remember where you were, just where you are, to know where you'll be. ("State is bad. Don't make the user think about it.")

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511279.aspx) says for Vista applications.

Answer (score 0):

Though the above answers are mechanically correct, using the arrows in said situation is not a good practice. Arrows are great for advancing records as an alternative or alongside previous/next buttons, but in the example it is better to use the tab and shift + tab keys because you can follow the tab order and skip any fields you don't want to be included.

For example, you tab from A to B then C, but if C is set to tab is disabled the tab will go directly from B to D. Then shift + tab will skip C again and go from D to B then to A.

It's not always how should I do it, but often why should I not.